# I am getting a org.springframework.web.bind.MissingPathVariableException

Tags: mysql, reactjs, spring-boot, rest

I am using spring boot RestApi backend and react frontend. I am using axios to get data from database

```
const API_URL_EX = 'http://localhost:8080/api/test/expense';

getExpense(userId){
    return axios.get(API_URL_EX + '/'+userId);
  }
```

```
 componentDidMount(){
        const currentUser = AuthService.getCurrentUser();
        let userId = {...this.state.userId};
        userId = currentUser.id;
        this.setState({userId});

        UserService.getExpense(userId).then((res) =>{
            this.setState({expense: res.data});
        },
        error => {
            this.setState({
              content:
                (error.response &&
                  error.response.data &&
                  error.response.data.message) ||
                error.message ||
                error.toString()
            });
          }
        );
    }
```

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000", maxAge = 3600)
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/test")
public class ExpenseController {
    @Autowired
    ExpenseRepository expenseRepository;
    @GetMapping("/expense/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getExpense(@PathVariable Long userId){
        Optional<Expense> expense = expenseRepository.findByUserId(userId);
        return expense.map(response -> ResponseEntity.ok().body(response))
                .orElse(new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND));
    }
}
```

I am trying to get data from mysql database but I am getting this error, I am passing the correct id as pathvariable

```
[org.springframework.web.bind.MissingPathVariableException: Required URI template variable 'userId' for method parameter type Long is not present]
```

Comment: `@GetMapping("/expense/{userId}")`

Comment: Thank you I have been stuck with this for too long

Answer (score 2):

Unless you specify path variable's name, path variable's name and method argument's name should match. Just change `id` to `userId` and it will work.

```
@GetMapping("/expense/{userId}")
public ResponseEntity<?> getExpense(@PathVariable Long userId){
    Optional<Expense> expense = expenseRepository.findByUserId(userId);
    return expense.map(response -> ResponseEntity.ok().body(response))
            .orElse(new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND));
}
```

Another option is to specify the name of the path variable. In that case names don't have to match.

```
@GetMapping("/expense/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<?> getExpense(@PathVariable("id") Long userId){
    Optional<Expense> expense = expenseRepository.findByUserId(userId);
    return expense.map(response -> ResponseEntity.ok().body(response))
            .orElse(new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND));
}
```

You can read [this article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-pathvariable) to learn more about `@PathVariable` annotation.